# Исключение COM в C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Помогите, вот бьюсь с исключением, не знаю что делать, в документации ничего нет.

Вылазит: **Проверьте свойство ErrorCode исключения.**

На строке:

```
skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, SkypeCommandHandler(msg.Body.Replace("!", "")));
```

Работаю со skype api, пытаюсь отправить сообщение по скайпу, что не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в отладчике тип возникающего исключения, перехватите экземпляр этого исключения и выведите его свойство `ErrorCode`. Потом гуглите значение этого `ErrorCode`.

Comment: у меня это COMException вообще нету